# Procedures on lists (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, procedure

I am writing a procedure which returns a list with all of the negative odd and positive
even integers removed (strings can stay), by using lambda in the primitive filter procedure. I also am avoiding using recursion, but that is what's stumping me.
What I have so far is:

```
(define (f2b lst)
    (cond ((null? lst)'()) ; if the list is empty, return the empty list
          ((pair? (car lst))  ; if the current element isn't a list   
              (filter (lambda (x) (or (even? x) (positive? x))) (car lst))
              (filter (lambda (x) (or (odd?  x) (negative? x))) (car lst))) 

 (else (string? (car lst))  ;otherwise, if the current element is a string,
            (car lst)       ; then return that element         
            (f2b (cdr lst)))))
```

I'm also not sure how I can apply both of the filter procedures at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's way simpler than that. All you have to do is `filter` the list. You just need the appropriate predicate.

When do you want to keep an element? You phrased it in terms of what you want to remove, so let's start with that. You want to remove if it's a negative odd or a positive even integer, and leave everything else in. It's easier to break it down into smaller functions.

```
(define (positive-even? x) (and (positive? x) (even? x)))
(define (negative-odd? x) (and (negative? x) (odd? x)))
(define (remove-num? x) (or (positive-even? x) (negative-odd? x)))
```

This defines whether to keep a number. But the list element might not be a number. So we 
keep it if it's not a number, or if it doesn't match `remove-num?`:

```
(define (keep-element? x) (or (not (number? x)) (not (remove-num? x))
```

Then your function just has to call filter:

```
(define (f2b lst) (filter keep-element? lst))
```

Seems to work:

```
(f2b '(-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 "a string" "another"))   
=> (-4 -2 0 1 3 "a string" "another")
```

---

Here's how it would look as one big honkin' function:

```
(define (f2b lst)
  (filter
   (lambda (x)
    (or (not (number? x)) 
        (not (or (and (positive? x) (even? x))
                 (and (negative? x) (odd? x))))))
   lst)
```

Personally, the nested `or not or and` gets a bit hard to read for my taste...

---

Ok, apparently you have nested lists. All you have to do here is `map` the result of the `filter` with a function which:

- when given a list, returns `(f2b lst)`
- otherwise, returns the element unchanged.

I will leave it as an exercise for you since, if you thought my function could possibly work on a nested list, clearly you have a lot of learning to do...

Comment: I tried running this code, but it just ran through my test case and printed the entire list. edit: i should have clarified, i was running it through a nested list.

Comment: @user2789945: you ran the last function i gave? what was the input you gave it?

Comment: yes, it works on regular lists, but when I passed it through a nested list, it printed the entire list.

Comment: @user2789945: oh, maybe you should mention that you have nested lists in the question?